# Split Time in Seconds for each Hour in a day given start and end time in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Input: Table time has State and Two timestamps (start and end time) for each.

```
user  state      start_time                end_time
1     Work    2022-08-15 11:00:38     2022-08-15 14:11:03
1     Break   2022-08-15 14:11:03     2022-08-15 14:25:25
1     Work    2022-08-15 14:25:25     2022-08-15 15:09:10
1     Work    2022-08-15 15:09:10     2022-08-15 15:14:15
1     Break   2022-08-15 15:14:15     2022-08-15 18:07:50
1     Work    2022-08-15 18:07:50     2022-08-15 19:25:31
1     Work    2022-08-15 19:25:31     2022-08-15 19:34:57
1     Work    2022-08-15 19:34:57     2022-08-15 20:10:57
1     Work    2022-08-15 20:10:57
```

Requirement:Find the total time spent on "work"(in seconds)between each hour.
For example: if we need time spent by user working between 7-8PM the output should be 3593 sec

I was able to get this but say for example we want the worktime from 8 - 9 (which is 10 min as per output) , the below code is unable to get that

Generate series doesnt seem to work on redshift

```
generate_series (start_timestamp, end_time - interval '1 sec', interval '1 sec')
```

Code so far:

```
select user,start_time,
   extract(epoch from (end_time-start_time)) as seconds
   from times
   where  TO_CHAR(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2022-08-15 19:00:00'
   and TO_CHAR(end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < '2022-08-15 20:00:00'
   and state = 'Work'
 union all
select user,start_time,
 extract(epoch from ((('2022-08-15 20:00:00')::timestamp)- 
      start_time)) as seconds
 from times
 where  TO_CHAR(start_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2022-08-15 19:00:00'
 and TO_CHAR(end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2022-08-15 19:00:00'
 and TO_CHAR(start_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < '2022-08-15 20:00:00'
 and state = 'Work'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things - you can replace generate_series() with a recursive cte, since you desire hour totals you just want to generate a series of hours, and it is not a good idea to use key words like "user" as column names.

Also it isn't clear what you want done with the last row - assume end of hour, end of day, or just ignore.  I went with ignore but changing this is straight forward.

I'd approach it this way:

```
create table test (
  "user" int,
  state varchar(16),
  start_time timestamp,
  end_time timestamp);

insert into test values
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 11:00:38', '2022-08-15 14:11:03'),
(1, 'Break', '2022-08-15 14:11:03', '2022-08-15 14:25:25'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 14:25:25', '2022-08-15 15:09:10'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 15:09:10', '2022-08-15 15:14:15'),
(1, 'Break', '2022-08-15 15:14:15', '2022-08-15 18:07:50'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 18:07:50', '2022-08-15 19:25:31'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 19:25:31', '2022-08-15 19:34:57'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 19:34:57', '2022-08-15 20:10:57'),
(1, 'Work', '2022-08-15 20:10:57',NULL);

with recursive hours(hr) as (
  select '2022-08-15 00:00:00'::timestamp as hr
  union all
  select hr + interval '1 hour'
  from hours
  where hr < '2022-08-15 23:00:00'),
relevants as (
  select * 
  from test t
  join hours h
  on t.start_time < h.hr + interval '1 hour'
        and t.end_time >= h.hr
  where t.state = 'Work'),
within_hour as (
  select "user", state,
    case when start_time < hr
       then hr
       else start_time end as start_time,
    case when end_time > hr + interval '1 hour'
       then  hr + interval '1 hour'
       else end_time end as end_time
  from relevants)
select *, extract(epoch from end_time) - 
            extract(epoch from start_time) as work_sec
from within_hour;
```

I broke the query out into CTE steps to view what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Weiner, this was awesome! also, yes i did have to ignore the last row